# insert data from listview into database delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, delphi-xe3

i'm searching an example how to save data from listview into database.

i have a listview with some data:

[image]

and database mysql:

ID, name, position, sall, date

can someone show me an example how to do this?

thx.

Comment: What are you tried? which db components are you using?

Comment: i'm using UniDac(devart.com) db component, i can't try.. because i can't filling how to start, can you give me some tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if TUNIQuery has ExecSql method but this will work with TADOQuery, in my case the ListView.ViewStyle is set to vsReport and it contains 4 cols.

I think if you use a StringGrid or a Dbgrid will be much easier to handel

```
procedure TForm1.PostData;
const
  SQLCMD = 'INSERT INTO MYTABLE (NAME, POSITION, SALL, DATE) VALUES '+
  '(%s, %s, %s, %s)';
var
//  IL: TListItem;
  I, J, ItemsCount, SubItemsCount: integer;
  LineItem: array of string;
begin

  ItemsCount:= ListView1.Items.Count;
  for I := 0 to ItemsCount - 1 do // looping thru the items
  begin
    SubItemsCount:= ListView1.Items[I].SubItems.count;
    SetLength(LineItem, SubItemsCount + 1);
    LineItem[0]:= ListView1.Items[0].Caption; // the first item caption (first col)
    for J := 0 to SubItemsCount - 1 do   // looping thru the subitems of each line
      LineItem[J+1]:= ListView1.Items[I].SubItems.Strings[J];
//
//  just to see the sql command
//    ShowMessage(
//    Format(SQLCMD, [ QuotedStr(LineItem[0]),
//                     QuotedStr(LineItem[1]),
//                     LineItem[2], //int field no need to quote the parameter
//                     QuotedStr(LineItem[3])]
//    ));

//
    with TAdoQuery.Create(nil) do
    try
      ConnectionString:= 'Your Connection String';
      SQL.Text:=
      Format(SQLCMD, [QuotedStr(LineItem[0]),
                      QuotedStr(LineItem[1]),
                      LineItem[2], //int field no need to quote the parameter
                      QuotedStr(LineItem[3]));
      ExecSql; // you might handel execsql to know the row was affected, also not sure if unidac have the same method
    finally
      Free;
    end;

    SetLength(LineItem, 0);

  end;
end;
```

Comment: thanks for your attention, i will check it later and give back  reports

Answer (score 1):

The following solution uses a TSQLQuery, which means that I am connecting to Firebird. I am sure that there are other query components which will give you the same result.

```
 with dstlist do  // this is the list view
  for i:= 1 to items.count do
   with qInsert do   // this is the query component
    begin
     dstlist.itemindex:= i - 1;
     lvitem:= dstlist.selected;   // select the correct node
     close;
     parambyname ('p1').asstring:= lvitem.caption;  // name
     parambyname ('p2').asstring:= lvitem.subitems[0];  // position
     parambyname ('p3').asinteger:= strtoint (lvitem.subitems[1]);  // sall
     parambyname ('p4').asdate:= strtodate (lvitem.subitems[2]);
     execsql;
    end;
```

The query itself would be something like

```
insert into table (name, position, sall, adate)
values (:p1, :p2, :p3, :p4)
```